# Appium inspector 1.2.6 cannot refresh after clicking alertdialog

Tags: android, appium, android-alertdialog

Consider below code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        show(this, "someTitle", "testing")
    }

    fun show(context: Context, title: String, message: String) {
        AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_Dialog)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, { dialog, _ ->
                    dialog.dismiss()
                })
                .setCancelable(false)
                .show()
    }
}
```

When launching Appium Inspector, and pressing refresh, everything works:

[image]

After clicking "OK" and pressing refresh, Appium cannot refresh the page anymore and keeps loading. If I would execute tests it would say "can not find element with ID x":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I built apk with exact same code and it works for me with [Appium-Desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.2.6) 1.2.6 (Mac OS Sierra), I was using this capabilities:

```
 "platformName": "Android",
 "app": <path to apk>,
 "deviceName": "android",
 "packageName": "com.demo.dmitry.demoapp",
 "appWaitActivity": "com.demo.dmitry.demoapp.MainActivity",
 "automationName": "UiAutomator2"
```

I click `OK` with button tap in inspector right panel and automatic inspector refresh finished successfully.